# Srcref error with list of functions and embedded comments

Tags: r

Has anyone experienced the following problem?

I'm working with a list that contains a number of functions. These functions have some comments that describe they do, and the comments can be rather long. If I copy and paste my code from my editor into R, and the comments get *too* long, R (version 2.14, 32-bit, on Windows) doesn't seem to like it.

Here's a simple (if long) example. `lf` contains 3 items, each of which is a function. Each function is preceded by a big comment block.

```
lf <- list(
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    f1 = function(x)
    x,

#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    f2 = function(x)
    x,

#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
#00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    f3 = function(x)
    x
)
```

When I copy and paste that code into R and then try to display a particular function, I get an error:

```
> lf$f3
Error in `Encoding<-`(`*tmp*`, value = enc) : 
  'value' must be of positive length
```

However, the error doesn't appear in R 2.12.2 (32 bit, Windows):

```
> lf$f3
function(x)
    x
```

The error also disappears in 2.14 if I save my code and then `source` it into my R session, or if I remove the big comment blocks. The latter can be achieved by either deleting them from my code and then copying-and-pasting, or by directly setting the `srcref` attribute to `NULL` for the offending functions.

```
lf2 <- list(
    f1 = function(x)
    x,
    f2 = function(x)
    x,
    f3 = function(x)
    x
)

lf3 <- lapply(lf, function(x) { attr(x, "srcref") <- NULL; x })


> lf2$f3
function(x)
    x

> lf3$f3
function (x) 
x
```

None of this seems to affect the actual functionality of the code itself; the functions work as intended when called. It's only the displaying of the source that causes errors.

Comment: I think you'd be better off reporting this on r-help/r-devel.